# If I create a new Facebook account on safari will it automatically log me out of my current account that I’m logged into on the Facebook app?

Tags: ios, safari, facebook

I need to know if I create a new Facebook on safari will it log me out of my current Facebook that I’m logged into on the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

No, the app’s accounts and Safari’s accounts are independent.